# Why the Calculation needs to be done on Complex way?

Tags: c++

I am expecting the fully calculated output clearly by

**just doing:**  But the problem is the program giving the output of **6%** **Tax** which is opposite of my expectations.
lrooms = 1 and srooms = 3, the result should 116.6 but it's not.

```
cout << "The total cost is: "<<(((lrooms*35)+(srooms*25))*0.06)<<'\n';
```

**and by doing this the output is given as expected:**

```
cout<<"The total cost is:
"<<((lrooms*35)+(srooms*25))+(((lrooms*35)+(srooms*25))*0.06)<<"$"<<'\n';
```

**The Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void services();

int main ()
{
    services();
    return 0;
}
void services()
{

        cout << "Enter the Quantity of Large rooms that you want to be cleaned: ";
        double lrooms{};
        cin >> lrooms;
        cout << "Enter the Quantity of Small rooms that you want to be cleaned: ";
        double srooms{};
        cin >> srooms;
      //cout << "The total cost is: "<<(((lrooms35)+(srooms25))*0.06)<<'\n';
        cout << "The total cost is: " << ((lrooms * 35) + (srooms * 25)) + (((lrooms * 35) + (srooms * 25)) * 0.06) << "$" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what the expected output should be.

Comment: You may want `cout << "The total cost is: "<<(((lrooms*35)+(srooms*25))*1.06)<<'\n';`

Comment: Your problem isn't a _programming_ problem in your _code_: it's understanding what you want to do and how to do it.  Think about the problem statement and the arithmetic calculations you need to do more fully and you'll be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: @cigien It depends on the user input

Comment: Yes, but *how* does it depend?

Comment: @IndianaJones Then showing some pairs of input and expected output for that will be useful.

Comment: Stop and think about what multiplying something by 0.06 does. Pull out a pencil and some paper and do the math by hand. Watch what happens. Then correct the formula and simplify.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just doing it by 1.06 solved the problem yes, Thank you

Comment: @cigien lrooms = 1 and srooms = 3, the result should 116.6 but it was not but 6.6 when doing with 0.06. 1.06 really solved the problem

Comment: Cool that 1.06 really solved the problem but make sure you know _why_ it solved the problem ...

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the kind of information that should be in the questions you post.

Comment: @cigien You are welcome, I have edited and added the info in the question.

Comment: @davidbak Yes I am trying to get this information and will share if I will Get it )

Comment: @user4581301 Yes the same I have done but not figured out

Comment: That's much better :) But "*and changing to 1.06 really solved the problem*" shouldn't really be part of the question. You should remove that, and instead make an answer, preferably with an explanation :)

Comment: @cigien Yes I edited again and Will post an answer with Explanation.

Comment: @MikeCAT Can you explain how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lrooms = 1 and srooms = 3, the result should 116.6 but it was not but 6.6 when doing with 0.06 and when changed to 1.06 really solved the problem.
The solution Provided by: @MikeCAT

```
cout << "The total cost is: "<<(((lrooms*35)+(srooms*25))*1.06)<<'\n';
```

But Still I don't know why it solved the problem just changing 0.06 to 1.06

Comment: Multiplying by 0.06 calculates 6% _of_ the input, which is indeed 6.6.  Multiplying by 1.06 calculates the 100% of the input with an additional  6%, which is indeed 116.6.

Comment: @MooingDuck This is what Exactly I want to understand, how this magic happened.

Comment: It's... not magic. I literally just explained the math.  Multiplying a number by 0.06 will result in 6% of the original number. When you want 100% of the original number plus an additional 6% of the number, you multiply it by 106% (100% + 6% = 106%), which is 1.06.  There's no magic or even programming things here, this is just 6th grade math. You're overthinking it :)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for the explanation) now its all clear